# How to see what get_fundamentals is adding to universe

Tags: python, printing, stock, quantitative-finance

I have a simple python code with searches the market for companies with specific financial criteria.

Code:

```
num_stocks = 2
fundamental_df  = get_fundamentals(
    query(
    fundamentals.valuation.market_cap,
    fundamentals.income_statement.net_income
    )
    .filter(fundamentals.income_statement.net_income > 1)
    .order_by(fundamentals.valuation.market_cap)
    .desc())
    .limit(num_stocks)
    )
update_universe(fundamental_df.columns.values)
context.stocks = [stock for stock in fundamental_df]

for stock in context.stocks:
    print stock
```

Im want to see if it is working/what companies it is querying.
I tried having my algo print what whats inside context.stocks but its not work.

Could someone help me out,

Thanks
Mike

Comment: what do you man by it does not work? have you checked `fundamental_df` if it contains anything and is pulling data?

Comment: @danidee I tried:
    for stock in fundamental_df:
        print stocks
However my logs doesn't seem to populate anything
(I'm very new to python, so I'm not surprised that I'm doing something wrong)

Comment: That means it's empty...so you should probably check your query because it seems not to be pulling anything from your data source...that's if you're sure there is any data there

Comment: @Mike it should be `print stock`, not `print stocks`

Comment: @Natecat I just gave that a go, however unfortunately still no luck. I figure either the data just isn't getting fetched or I am incorrectly trying to access it for the print function. (Possibly the data is in the wrong format or something?)